# Pafy+Youtub_dl+OpenCV is slow to display videos

Tags: python, opencv, youtube-dl, pafy

I am trying a basic example of displaying a youtube video using opencv, and I seem to get 50% or less of the framerate as in the browser.  Eventually I want to make a real-time computer vision application from youtube streams (well, a fixed delay is fine, but I want it to be able to keep up), and so if just displaying a video is slow, I'm not sure how that is going to happen.  Does anyone know which part of this is slow?  And is there a way to speed it up?

```
import cv2
import pafy
import youtube_dl

url = 'https://youtu.be/1AbfRENy3OQ'
urlPafy = pafy.new(url)
videoplay = urlPafy.getbest()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoplay.url)

while(True):
    # Capture image frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: **profile** your code. you need to figure out which parts take how much time. -- OpenCV is for computer vision. it's not for making GUIs, and it's also not for decoding video streams properly (even though it has basic facilities for both). use a proper GUI toolkit (pick one, Qt or wxwidgets maybe?) and a proper video processing library (PyAV, perhaps imageio)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a bug in youtube_dl: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/29326 that essentially caused youtube to throttle the connection.